# Only 'Import keras' takes 10GB in GPU

Tags: memory, tensorflow, memory-leaks, keras, gpu

I am using EC2 GPU machine with pre-made AMIs.
I just put 'import keras' and run it.
It takes 11519MiB ( out of 12181MiB).
It's non-sense right?

I did googling it. I guess it might come from the path setting.
I don't know which causes memory leak.

Anyone who know the solution or experience similar with me??

--UPDATE--
It is the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my company's GPU server
When I used the server at the first time, Only tensorflow was installed, not tensorflow-gpu. So I just did 'pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu'
[image]

Comment: you are saying only "import keras" load 10GB into GPU?

Comment: Whoa.... have you followed the Cuda 8.0 and the cuDNN 6.0 installation guides step by step? Have you installed ONLY `tensorflow-gpu` v1.3 (this is the correct to do) and not `tensorflow`? --- There is a new tensorflow 1.4, but I'm not used to it, I've only installed 1.3 so far.

Comment: I just updated my question. I think other people in my compnay use this GPU server well. (BUT only tensorflow? I am not sure...) I just downloaded 'tensorflow-gpu'..

Comment: 'import tensorflow' takes no memory in GPU. Keras takes memory as I said

Comment: Tensorflow installation guide says you should have "only" tensorflow-gpu, not tensorflow. I'd try creating a separate environment for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem.

It is related to Keras & Tensorflow Memory allocation problem.
My setting automatically allocated all memory in GPU.
I solve it by the below.
Anyway, Thanks all

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.2)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.2
session = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
```